# How can I change the width of the container?

Tags: html, css

I have [this site](http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/index.php/project-space/).

If you click past exhibition you will see images and dark gray container which is great.

I put an image to understand better what I want to do.

I do not want a fixed size ... somehow I want to be automatically

[image]

**HTML + CSS:**

```
<div class="container-left" style="width:100%;background:grey;"> 
            <div class="contentt"></div>


          <div class="imagini">  
            <div class="lista-sus">
                <div class="gigi" style="float:left;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/a.png" alt="some_text"></div>
                <div class="gigi"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/b.png" alt="some_text"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="lista-jos"> 
                <div class="gigi" style="float:left;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/c.png" alt="some_text"></div>
                <div class="gigi"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/d.png" alt="some_text"></div>   
            </div>
              <div class="sageti">
                  <div  style="float:left;"><img class="sageata-stanga" src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/butoane-1.png" alt="some_text"></div>
                  <div ><img class="sageata-dreapta" src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/butoane-4.png" alt="some_text"></div>
              </div>
```

I tried `.container-left{width:auto;}`but unfortunately it does not work and do not understand why

You can help me solve this problem please?

Comment: you mean width percentage?

Comment: i want width:auto...if it`s possible

Comment: I m not sure I understand what you want to do. is it to spread the 4 blocs to filld the container's width?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the block to filled in your container width: Add this

```
.gigi {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

Now if you want your image to fill up also these blocks, you have to use put this style

```
background-image:url('my/url');
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
```

If you try to use this method you have add a height in .gigi div because youre using a background-image now and the height is not specified